# How to logrotate kubernetes' log on windows node?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, logrotate

According to [k8s on Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows),i have deployed a windows k8s cluster(version 1.12.6) which has one master node on Linux Server and two worker nodes on Windows19 Server. However, the log file produced and locked by `kubelet`、 `kube-proxy` process occupied several GB disk space。what can I do to rotate the log file for just saving recent days' data on windows Server?

I know `Stop` and `Start` the `kubelet`、`kube-proxy` process will help, but my boss said no! :(

I have tried some ways:

1. [window logrotate tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/logrotatewin/)

```
# logrotate config
"c:\k\log\kube-proxy.exe.iZcrhcz0q5s4ykZ.NT AUTHORITY_SYSTEM.log.INFO.20190416-162533.2272" {
    daily
    rotate 5
    size 100M
    copytruncate
    missingok
    ifempty
}
```

2. powershell cmd

```
rm xxx.log
mv xxx.log
Clear-Content -Path $logFile -Force
```

All failed!

Error Message: `The process cannot access the file 'C:\k\log\xxx.log' because it is being used by another process.`

I have some questions:

- 1: Does k8s' log system support logrotate on Windows?
- 2: Does Windows Server provide a mechanism to rotate log?

Thanks for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

kubelet/kube-proxy use klog, klog rotate when file size > 1.8G

```golang
func (sb *syncBuffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if sb.nbytes+uint64(len(p)) >= MaxSize {
        if err := sb.rotateFile(time.Now(), false); err != nil {
            sb.logger.exit(err)
        }
    }
    n, err = sb.Writer.Write(p)
    sb.nbytes += uint64(n)
    if err != nil {
        sb.logger.exit(err)
    }
    return
}
```

you can just delete older files.